# Number(i) is passed into the function in the code below.can someone explain how the loops are working in the code

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, return, boolean-logic

CODE:

```js
let para = document.createElement('p');

function isPrime(num) {
  for (let z = 2; z < num; z++) {
    if (num % z === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

for (i; i > 1; i--) {
  if (isPrime(i)) {
    para.textContent += `${i} `;
  }
}

let section = document.querySelector('section');
section.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<section></section>
```

output:

> 499 491 487 479 467 463 461 457 449 443 439 433 431 421 419 409 401
> 397 389 383 379 373 367 359 353 349 347 337 331 317 313 311 307 293
> 283 281 277 271 269 263 257 251 241 239 233 229 227 223 211 199 197
> 193 191 181 179 173 167 163 157 151 149 139 137 131 127 113 109 107
> 103 101 97 89 83 79 73 71 67 61 59 53 47 43 41 37 31 29 23 19 17 13 11
> 7 5 3 2

Comment: The script won't do anything (as you can see when you execute the snippet)

Comment: Please, be more specific: What do you mean by "how the loops are working"?
Should we explain you how the "for" loop works? Or maybe should we explain you how this code checks if the number is prime?

Comment: actually i  is initialized to 500.

Comment: By the way, as @Andreas mentioned above, this code is not working, because "i" in your second **for loop** is not declarated. If you want to get an output as in your post, you should change it to something like: `for( let i=500 ; i > 1 ; i-- )`

Comment: @Przemysław Niemiec can you please explain how this code checks if the number is prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your comment I can see, that actually you're asking about: "**How the code checks if the number is prime**".
So, at the begin, we should say, what is a "prime number".

```
Every natural number has both 1 and itself as a divisor. If it has any other divisor, it cannot be prime. ~Wikipedia
```

So, if the number **num** has any divisor between **1** and **num**, the isPrime() function should return **false**.

So, that's why your code is looking for every integer number between **1** and **num**:

```
for (let z = 2; z < num; z++)
```

But how to check if the number **z** is the divisor of number **num**?
To check it, you have to calculate the division remainder. If it's zero, **z** is the divisor of number **num**.

When we check all the numbers, and none of them is a divisor of **num**, we can say, that **num** is a prime number, because it has no divisor between 1 and itself.

```
function isPrime(num) {
  for (let z = 2; z < num; z++) {
    if (num % z === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```